# IP fragments order of arriving

Tags: networking, ip, network-protocols

Is it true that IP fragments must arrive in a strict order?
I mean can I always expect, that first I receive the 1-st IP fragment, than the 2-nd and so on... Or it's possible that after receiving the 1-st fragment, the next fragment will be the 3-rd and after that the 2-nd?

I can't find anywhere in RFCs about it.

Comment: No, it isn't true, but implementations are free to discard fragments that would 'leave a hole', so in effect it can be true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out the answer ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Fragmentation_and_reassembly)): When the receiver has all the fragments, **it can put them in the correct order, by using their offsets**. It can then pass their data up the stack for further processing